# How do I solve proxy error with React on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, react-on-rails

I am trying out this package: https://github.com/shakacode/react-webpack-rails-tutorial Following the instructions to set up hot reloading.

When running the project with `foreman start -f Procfile.hot` and refreshing the web page, I get 504 errors on the js bundle. In console I get this:

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /webpack/vendor-bundle-310d7ea8b116074b3610.js from localhost:3035 to http://lvh.me:3035 (ENFILE) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

I am not sure which part of the project that is causing this, how do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is: [`ENFILE Too many open files in system (POSIX.1-2001). On Linux, this is probably a result of encountering the proc/sys/fs/file-max limit (see proc(5)).`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html)

This is a system error and is not caused by the tutorial project itself. If you have a lot of applications open at one time, then closing some of them may resolve this error.